# Floating-point arithmetic issue (300.2 - 300 = 0.1999...)

Tags: javascript

**Description**

So I wrote the following calculation:

```
var valueWithoutIntegers = value - Math.floor(value);
```

This statement seems to do the job just fine, except when I had the value `value = 300.2`. So basically I had :

```
0.19999999999998863 = 300.2 - Math.floor(300.2)
```

So I fiddle around quickly in my JavaScript console:

```
300.2 - Math.floor(300.0) // gives 0.19999999999998863
300.2 - Math.floor(300.1) // gives 0.19999999999998863
300.2 - Math.floor(300.0) // gives 0.19999999999998863
300.2 - 300               // gives 0.19999999999998863
300.2 - 300.1             // gives 0.0999999999999659
```

So I was all like... **WTF** right? But I thought, maybe I need to help the laws of physics, I mean floating points in computer science. So I googled a bit and tried out:

```
Number((300.2).toFixed(2)) - Number((300.2).toFixed(0)) // gives 0.19999999999998863
Number((300.2).toFixed(2)) - Number((300.2).toFixed(2)) // gives 0, makes sense!
300.2 - Number((300.2).toFixed(0))                      // gives 0.19999999999998863
Number(300.2) - Number(300)                             // gives 0.19999999999998863
```

Yikes ! Feel free to run any of these statements in your JavaScript console. I ran it in my Google Chrome and in my local Node.JS application.

**So my questions**

- Where does this magic come from? I don't see why this would be a corner case, I only used 1 number after the decimal! Not like, 200.
- How can I refactor my statement, so I won't have to deal with this or other edge cases?

Comment: @JJJ let me check it out

Comment: In short: computers don't do decimal math (unless otherwise noted) and cannot store infinite digits.

Comment: `1/5` in binary is like `1/7` in decimal, you can't represent them exactly.

Comment: Do not use `toFixed` if you are going to subtract the result. Just use `toFixed` on the result.